# Why text wont display in html

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

why will the text in html `h4` not displayed.
It will show fine in 2 out of 3 time, but one time it will fail to show the text.

Now if i just toggle any css property on this element it will showup.
***Any idea when can this happen ?***
Any thoughts will be welcome

**EDIT::**
Sorry for the mistake in pic editing

I do have `<h4> some text here</h4>`

Please note as mentioned:
**Now if i just toggle any css property on this element it will showup.**
[image]

Comment: You have 3 JavaScript errors. Can you show them? Also, maybe there's something displayed over your element.

Comment: Do you need it to be inside h4 tag and not between?

Comment: show us the full html file and css please, also the js errors, oh btw you have overflow auto at body, what if u remove that?

Comment: js error is related the resource not loading

Comment: Also the problem only occur 2 out of 3 time

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a text in your `h4` just wrap your text inside of its tags:

```
<h4> Some text here! </h4>
```

Comment: Please refer the edit , sorry for mistake in pic editing

Comment: @user2410148 Can you provide a link to a working example please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if angular render it in another moment, the devTool is on the rendered html page, but in your html the text is inside a data element and not inside h4 tag:

```
<h4 data-ng-show="Some text here!" > </h4>
```

should be at least:

```
<h4 data-ng-show="Some text here!" >Some text here!</h4>
```

Comment: Please refer the edit section , sorry for the mistake in pic editing

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies not with the not showing of the text,
the problem lies with the place of the text.

---

**syntaxis**

The proper syntaxis for the `<h*>` tags is: `<h*>{text to display here}</h*>`.

---

**Your syntaxis**

The syntaxis that you are using is: `<h4 data-ng-show="Some text here!" > </h4>`.

---

**conclusion/solution**

The `<h*>` tag is properly showing what you are telling it to show: , place the text you want shown in between the `<h*>` and the `</h*>` and it will show up.

Comment: Please refer the edit section , sorry for the mistake in pic editing

Answer (score 0):

I think the guys pretty much covered how you probably should be using just `<h4>`. But to add on to what has been said already, `data-ng-show` takes Boolean expression (e.g. water != fire) NOT strings.

E.g. Given that showText is true

```
<h4 data-ng-show="showText" >Some text here</h4>
```

Comment: Please refer the edit section , sorry for the mistake in pic editing